# Is there a way to map all HTML elements and child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html format and would like it to loop through all children's children, etc.

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span></span>
                    <a>
                        <span></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</body>
```

The output should be in array where i can display in this format.

```
header
    div
        ul
            li
                span
                a
                    span
main
    div
    div
footer
    ul
        li
            a
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t see how the output maps to an array. What are you actually trying to do with this output? There’s `document.querySelectorAll("*")`, [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker), [`NodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator), but you could simply use the DOM API for manipulation and querying.

Comment: I want to display the output in that format. Using simply `document.querySelectorAll("*")` will not arrange in that format.

Answer (score 0):

Below is recursive method to loop through DOM tree.

```js
function loopDOMTree(parent) {
    var treeString = "";
    function loopTree(parent2, tabs) {
        treeString += tabs + parent2.tagName + "\n";
        for (let tag of parent2.children) {
            if (tag.childElementCount == 0) {
                treeString += tabs + '\t' + tag.tagName + "\n";
            } else {
                loopTree(tag, tabs + '\t')
            }
        }
    }
    loopTree(parent, "");
    return treeString;
}
console.log(loopDOMTree(document.body));
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span></span>
                    <a>
                        <span></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</body>
```